# RegExp есть 1 инпут и 3 дива, если пишем цифру то показывает в первом диве, если буквы то в втором и если англ, буквы в третем диве,

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
but.addEventListener('click', f);

function f() {
  val = inp.value;
  let str = '';
  let reg = /str/;
  d.innerHTML += (str.match(reg));

  let str1 = '';
  let reg1 = /\w+/gi;
  dd.innerHTML += (str1.match(reg1));

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="but">ok</button>
<div class="d1" id="d"></div>
<div class="d1" id="dd"></div>
<div class="d1" id="ddd"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
but.addEventListener('click', f);

function f() {
  let sVal = inp.value[0];
  if (/[0-9]/.test(sVal)) {
    d.innerHTML += sVal;
  } else if (/[а-яё]/i.test(sVal)) {
    dd.innerHTML += sVal;
  } else if (/[a-z]/i.test(sVal)) {
    ddd.innerHTML += sVal;
  }
  inp.value = ''; inp.focus();
}
```

```css
div.d1 { margin: 5px 0; height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #080; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="but">ok</button>
<div class="d1" id="d"></div>
<div class="d1" id="dd"></div>
<div class="d1" id="ddd"></div>
```

Comment: спосибо, по скольку inp.value не массыв я удалил [0],  работает все

Comment: @Мосо: если ввести несколько символов, то уже массив. `[0]` берёт только первый символ, независимо от того сколько введено.